# How to create JSONObject from ArrayList<Object> to make post request?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to post data into server using JSONObject as request. And I dont know how to create JSONObject from ArrayList with following type of data.

```
{"AnswersList":[
{
    "questionID": 1,
    "question": "What is yout name?",
    "questionType": "STRI",
    "questionOrder": 1,
    "answer":"Avishek",
    "choiceList": []
},
{
    "questionID": 2,
    "question": "Sports?",
    "questionType": "MULT",
    "questionOrder": 2,
     "answer":"1,2",
    "choiceList": [
        {
            "choiceID": 1,
            "choiceName": "Football",
            "choiceOrder": 1
        },
        {
            "choiceID": 2,
            "choiceName": "Basketball",
            "choiceOrder": 2
        }
    ]
}]}
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.
I have create two model classes for handling the JSON. First one is Question.java for second is Choice.java

Model classes are:
Question.java

```
public class Question {

@SerializedName("questionID")
public String questionID;
@SerializedName("question")
public String question;
@SerializedName("questionType")
public String questionType;
@SerializedName("questionOrder")
public String questionOrder;
@SerializedName("answer")
public String answer;
@SerializedName("choiceList")
public ArrayList<Choice> choices = new ArrayList<>();
@SerializedName("isRequired")
public boolean isRequired;


//getter and setter methods
}
```

Choice.java

```
public class Choice {

@SerializedName("choiceID")
private String choiceID;

@SerializedName("choiceName")
private String choiceName;

@SerializedName("choiceOrder")
private String choiceOrder;


//getter and setter method
}
```

I've tried this code but did not work

```
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    ArrayList<Question> questionsAnswer = new ArrayList<>();
    questionsAnswer.addAll(databaseHelper.getQuestionList());

    Log.v(TAG, "size of question answer list : " + questionsAnswer.size());

    Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new ArrayMap<>();
    //put something inside the map, could be null
    JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(questionsAnswer);
    jsonParams.put("AnswersList", jsArray);
```

Comment: No sir, just a minute I am updating code I have done.

Comment: Sir can you check the code i've done. i Just want to create JSONObject from ArrayList<Object> so that I can post this JsonObject into server

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'll suggest to use Retrofit library for requests (https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

For creating a json String from your object you can use Gson library

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = gson.toJson(obj);
```

**Update**
don't forget to add Gson dependency on your gradle file

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing JSON Objects & Arrays on Java we should use **GSON** Library

Add gradle File:

**implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'**